# SEE server not working with join room at screen sharing RTCMultiConnection

Tags: php, webrtc, rtcmulticonnection

I am creating screen share with SEE server, everything is working properly
when the user opens a room for screen share he enters a room

But when the second user wants to turn it on room nothing happens

I checked and error gives no room found
How I can resolve that?

(i test script with socket.io server it's working properly)

my front end code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>SSE+PHP Signaling using RTCMultiConnection</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="logo.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
  <script src="menu.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <a class="logo" href="/"><img src="logo.png" alt="RTCMultiConnection"></a>
    <a href="/" class="menu-explorer">Menu<img src="menu-icon.png" alt="Menu"></a>
    <nav>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/demos/">Demos</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://www.rtcmulticonnection.org/docs/getting-started/">Getting Started</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://www.rtcmulticonnection.org/FAQ/">FAQ</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLPRQUXAnRydKdyun-vjKPMrySoow2N4tl">YouTube</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection/wiki">Wiki</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection">Github</a>
      </li>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <h1>
    SSE+PHP Signaling using RTCMultiConnection
    <p class="no-mobile">This demo is using SSE (Server Sent Events) to setup WebRTC one-to-one connection. <a href="https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection/tree/master/demos/SSEConnection">Check PHP Source Codes</a></p>
  </h1>

  <section class="make-center">
      <input type="text" id="room-id" value="abcdef" autocorrect=off autocapitalize=off size=20>
      <button id="open-room">Open Room</button>
      <button id="join-room">Join Room</button>
      <button id="open-or-join-room">Open or Join Room</button>

      <div id="room-urls" style="text-align: center;display: none;background: #F1EDED;margin: 15px -10px;border: 1px solid rgb(189, 189, 189);border-left: 0;border-right: 0;"></div>

      <div id="videos-container"></div>
  </section>

<script src="adapter.js"></script>
<script src="RTCMultiConnection.js"></script>
<script src="SSEConnection.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="getHTMLMediaElement.css">
<script src="getHTMLMediaElement.js"></script>
<script>
window.enableAdapter = true; // enable adapter.js

// ......................................................
// .......................UI Code........................
// ......................................................
document.getElementById('open-room').onclick = function() {
    disableInputButtons();
    connection.open(document.getElementById('room-id').value, function() {
        showRoomURL(connection.sessionid);
    });
};

document.getElementById('join-room').onclick = function() {
    disableInputButtons();

    connection.sdpConstraints.mandatory = {
        OfferToReceiveAudio: false,
        OfferToReceiveVideo: true
    };
    console.log(document.getElementById('room-id').value);
    connection.join(document.getElementById('room-id').value);
};

document.getElementById('open-or-join-room').onclick = function() {
    disableInputButtons();
    // connection.openOrJoin(document.getElementById('room-id').value);
    connection.checkPresence(document.getElementById('room-id').value, function(isRoomExist, roomid) {
      console.info('checkPresence', isRoomExist, roomid);

      if(isRoomExist) {
        connection.join(roomid);
      }
      else {
        connection.open(roomid);
      }
    });
};

// ......................................................
// ..................RTCMultiConnection Code.............
// ......................................................

var connection = new RTCMultiConnection();

// Using SSE (Server Sent Events) for signaling
connection.socketURL = 'https://127.0.0.1/see/';
connection.setCustomSocketHandler(SSEConnection);

connection.session = {
    screen: true,
    oneway: true
};

connection.sdpConstraints.mandatory = {
    OfferToReceiveAudio: true,
    OfferToReceiveVideo: true
};

// https://www.rtcmulticonnection.org/docs/iceServers/
// use your own TURN-server here!
connection.iceServers = [{
    'urls': [
        'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302',
        'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302',
        'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302',
        'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302?transport=udp',
    ]
}];

connection.videosContainer = document.getElementById('videos-container');
connection.onstream = function(event) {
    event.mediaElement.id = event.streamid;
    connection.videosContainer.appendChild(event.mediaElement);

    if (event.type === 'remote') {
        connection.socket.close(); // release SSE connection
    }
};

connection.onstreamended = function(event) {
    var mediaElement = document.getElementById(event.streamid);
    if (mediaElement && mediaElement.parentNode) {
        mediaElement.parentNode.removeChild(mediaElement);
    }
};

function disableInputButtons() {
    document.getElementById('open-room').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('join-room').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('open-or-join-room').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('room-id').disabled = true;
}

// ......................................................
// ......................Handling Room-ID................
// ......................................................

function showRoomURL(roomid) {
    var roomHashURL = '#' + roomid;
    var roomQueryStringURL = '?roomid=' + roomid;

    var html = '<h2>Unique URL for your room:</h2><br>';

    html += 'Hash URL: <a href="' + roomHashURL + '" target="_blank">' + roomHashURL + '</a>';
    html += '<br>';
    html += 'QueryString URL: <a href="' + roomQueryStringURL + '" target="_blank">' + roomQueryStringURL + '</a>';

    var roomURLsDiv = document.getElementById('room-urls');
    roomURLsDiv.innerHTML = html;

    roomURLsDiv.style.display = 'block';
}

(function() {
    var params = {},
        r = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g;

    function d(s) {
        return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
    }
    var match, search = window.location.search;
    while (match = r.exec(search.substring(1)))
        params[d(match[1])] = d(match[2]);
    window.params = params;
})();

var roomid = '';
if (localStorage.getItem(connection.socketMessageEvent)) {
    roomid = localStorage.getItem(connection.socketMessageEvent);
} else {
    roomid = connection.token();
}
document.getElementById('room-id').value = roomid;
document.getElementById('room-id').onkeyup = function() {
    localStorage.setItem(connection.socketMessageEvent, this.value);
};

var hashString = location.hash.replace('#', '');
if (hashString.length && hashString.indexOf('comment-') == 0) {
    hashString = '';
}

var roomid = params.roomid;
if (!roomid && hashString.length) {
    roomid = hashString;
}

if (roomid && roomid.length) {
    document.getElementById('room-id').value = roomid;
    localStorage.setItem(connection.socketMessageEvent, roomid);

    // auto-join-room
    connection.join(roomid);

    disableInputButtons();
}
</script>

  <footer>
    <small id="send-message"></small>
  </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP side :
https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection/tree/master/demos/SSEConnection

Comment: help us to help you. please show some code

Comment: Yes you are right, I added the codes